# Nhibernate merge of related entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, merge

I have a User object which has a UserProfile object associated with it, each has their own DB table. I have set up the hibernate mapping to cascade operations with a two-way mapping so that I can just call Save on the User object and it will automatically create the user profile object, inserting in the generated UserId in the key column in a single operation. This works fine. Hibernate mapping is as follows

```
<class name="User" table="[User]">
    <id name="UserId" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />
    <property name="EmailAddress" />
    <property name="DateOfBirth" />
    <property name="Gender" />
    <property name="PostcodePartOne" />
    <property name="PostcodePartTwo" />
    <many-to-one name="UserLocation" column="UserLocationId" />
    <property name="DateJoined" />
    <property name="LastLoggedOn" />
    <property name="Status"/>
    <property name="StatusNotes" />
    <one-to-one name="Profile" class="UserProfile" cascade="all" />
  </class>

<class name="UserProfile" table="UserProfile">
    <id name="UserProfileId" column="UserId">
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">User</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="User" class="User" constrained="true" />
    <property name="Height" />
    <many-to-one name="BodyType" column="BodyTypeId" />
    <many-to-one name="Ethnicity" column="EthnicityId" />
    <many-to-one name="MaritalStatus" column="MaritalStatusId"/>
    <property name="NumberOfChildren" />
    <many-to-one name="WantsChildren" column="WantsChildrenId" />
    <many-to-one name="Religion" column="ReligionId" />
    <many-to-one name="Drinking" column="DrinkingId" />
    <many-to-one name="Smoking" column="SmokingId" />
    <many-to-one name="Diet" column="DietId" />
    <many-to-one name="Education" column="EducationId" />
    <many-to-one name="Socialising" column="SocialisingId" />
    <many-to-one name="Travelling" column="TravellingId" />
    <many-to-one name="Romance" column="RomanceId" />
    <many-to-one name="SexualOpenness" column="SexualOpennessId" />
    <many-to-one name="SexualFrequency" column="SexualFrequencyId" />
    <many-to-one name="SharedInterests" column="SharedInterestsId" />
    <many-to-one name="TimeWithPartner" column="TimeWithPartnerId" />
    <many-to-one name="Ambition" column="AmbitionId" />
    <many-to-one name="Emigrating" column="EmigratingId" />
    <many-to-one name="FamilyInvolvement" column="FamilyInvolvementId" />
    <property name="LastUpdated" />
    <one-to-one name="ProfileText" class="UserProfileText" cascade="all" />
  </class>
```

What doesn't work is when I try and do a detached update. I create a new User and UserProfile object, linking them with references to each other just like I do when I save, then assign the User.UserId to the saved user Id that I want to update. I then call session.merge(user) but get the below error

```
    Message "Error updating item of type 'User':a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 153, of entity: UserProfile" string
```

Is this telling me that it would be happy to merge the User object but for some reason is not able to merge the User Profile?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the UserProfile you assign to the User loaded in another session?

Comment: I only have one session active. What I do is (pseudo code) userOne = new User(details1); Session.Save(userOne). userTwo = new User(details2); userTwo.UserId = userOne.UserId; Session.Merge(userTwo);

Comment: And where does the UserProfile come from? Where are you executing this pseudo code? Do you have a dao?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the problem. I was setting the UserProfiles "User" property reference to the parent User object, but I wasn't setting it's "UserId" property it has as the PK, so it thought it belonged to the parent User but still had a zero for it's UserId identifier. Setting the UserId on the Profile object as well as the User object worked